# CSS scrolling left on zoomed image

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

When zooming a centered image with overflow:auto there is no possibility to scroll to the left, even when the picture overflows the left border of the surrounding div.

The image should be centered and grow to left and right in the same way. When the wrappers size is reached, scrollbars should appear.

Is there any solution for this?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zoom</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #666666;
        }

        .content {
            background: #C3C3C3;
            width: 80%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .img-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: auto;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .my-image {
            height: 400px;
            transform-origin: top;
        }

        .slidecontainer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 47%;
            background: #0b1e2a;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="content">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img id="bacon" class="my-image"
             src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cooked-bacon-rashers-closeup-isolated-on-a-white-background-picture-id508755080?s=2048x2048"/>
    </div>

    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="img-slider">
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function zoom(id, value) {
        var scale = "scale(" + value + ");"
        var style = "-ms-transform:" + scale + "-webkit-transform:" + scale + "transform:" + scale;
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style", style);
    }


    var imgSlider = document.getElementById("img-slider");
    imgSlider.oninput = function () {
        multiplier = 3;
        var zoomlevel = 1 + this.value / 100 * multiplier;
        zoom("bacon", zoomlevel);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try updated code

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Zoom</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #666666;
        }

        .content {
            background: #C3C3C3;
            width: 80%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .img-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: auto;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        .my-image {
            height: 400px;
            transform-origin: top;
        }

        .slidecontainer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 47%;
            background: #0b1e2a;
        }
        </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="img-wrapper" id="img-wrapper">
            <img id="bacon" class="my-image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cooked-bacon-rashers-closeup-isolated-on-a-white-background-picture-id508755080?s=2048x2048" />
        </div>

        <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="img-slider">
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function zoom(id, value) {
            var outerDiv = document.getElementById('img-wrapper');
            var imgEle = document.getElementById(id);
            var scale = "scale(" + value + ");"
            var origin = "top";
            var translateX = '';
            if (outerDiv.clientWidth !== outerDiv.scrollWidth) {
                origin = "top left";
                translateX = ' translateX(' + (-imgEle.offsetLeft) + 'px) ';
            }

            var style = "-ms-transform:" + translateX + scale + "-webkit-transform:" + translateX + scale + "transform:" + translateX + scale + "transform-origin:" + origin + ";";
            document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style", style);

            outerDiv.scrollTop = outerDiv.scrollHeight / 2 - outerDiv.clientHeight / 2;
            outerDiv.scrollLeft = outerDiv.scrollWidth / 2 - outerDiv.clientWidth / 2;
        }


        var imgSlider = document.getElementById("img-slider");
        imgSlider.oninput = function () {
            multiplier = 3;
            var zoomlevel = 1 + this.value / 100 * multiplier;
            zoom("bacon", zoomlevel);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. One addition. It's now needed to move the image to the left by half of the wrappers size.

https://jsfiddle.net/6q147of8/

Comment: I couldn't get your requirement. Can you please send a screenshot of what you expect it to be.

Comment: If you zoom the image until there is enough space to scroll to the left hand side, scroll to the most left hand side. There is a vertical grey space that shouldn't be there. Moving the image with a negative margin-left doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.